# Percentage complete animation, circular form with status display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

[image]You would have seen something similar in Linkedin as well, which display the amount of profile it is completed, the All Star line moves up from the bottom.

So I have something similar wherein, I want to rotate the circle with the animation of the percentage completed. So I have done the circular animation for 50% completion as attached in the codepen link, but the other circle is the problem as I am clueless how to rotate it along with that animation.

Would love to get feedback from you all so that, I can update the codepen and can make it available for everyone to use.

The codepen link: [Circular percentage completion with CSS animation.`<html></html>`](http://codepen.io/abhilash27/pen/BWaBwv?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

Try any of them both link  are working

http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Basic-jQuery-Circular-Progress-Bar-Plugin-Circles/
http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Dynamic-Circular-Progress-Bar-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

Comment: Thanks for the two links, but I have a separate circle next to this if you will see the codepen link I sharedwhich will also move in a circular manner with number as it progresses. This, I already achieved in CSS without even using jQuery.